# python detecting usb ports when they are turned on and starting a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, usb, detection

Okay, I would like to upgrade my code for detecting ports and starting a thread once the port is available.  What I am currently doing is waiting for the expected number of ports to be there.  then I do a for loop to start the Thread.  Like I said, Currently I do a

```
subprocess.check_output('ls /tty' + number expected port) #to see if all ports are turned on. 

for port in portlist: 
    initialize the Thread object.
```

The problem is that the code that I have on the USB devices I have only 10 seconds to write to the device to tell it is in command mode.  So if I have like 10 devices that I want to program, if I don't turn them all on really fast, I won't be able to program the first couple of devices due to the fact that I am waiting to see all ports turned on...  Changing the time on the USB devices CANNOT BE CHANGED.

I would like to see the new port and then start the thread.  Can anyone help.  I hope I explained this well enough.  This is on a linux machine so the ports are assigned as they are turned on.

Comment: Are you looking for only serial ports? Did you mean `ls /dev/tty` instead of `ls /tty`? Have you looked at [`udev`](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) or [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)? Finally, it will help a lot if you provide a minimal working code sample that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Yes, I am only looking at serial ports.  The code works now by just calling the getportlist and then doing a for loop to start the thread.                                        def __getPortsList(self):
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_output('ls /dev/tty' + userPorts + '* 2>&1', shell = True)
            print result
            if 'ls: cannot access' in result:
                return ''
            else:
                return result
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            return ''